# Commutative rings exercise

Tags: ring-theory

I know that this may be quite common, but I'd like to know how would you approach the following exercise:

> Let $(R,+,*)$ be a ring such that $x^2-x \in Z(R), \forall x \in R.$ Show that $R$ is commutative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that $x^{2}-x,y^{2}-y\in Z(R)$ and 
$$(x+y)^{2}-(x+y)=(x^{2}-x)+(y^{2}-y)+xy+yx\in Z(R)$$
which implies that $xy+yx\in Z(R)$.